# How to find its integral curves.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Please should someone help me finding its integral curves.

$$\frac{dx}{x^2+b^2} =\frac{dy}{xy-bz}=\frac{dz}{xz+by}$$

By the way, its answers are the following.

$$c_1=\frac{xz+by}{bz-xy}$$ and $$c_2=c_1y+z$$

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525867/how-to-obtain-the-last-ratio-fracdxzxz

Comment: I know how to find. But I cannot do this one. Which calculations should I do? Thanks for the suggestion. But, this doesnt help me. Dear @abiessu

Comment: Please can you show me which calculations I sould do. @abiessu

Comment: From what I can see, you have $c_1=-\frac {dz}{dy}=\frac {xz+by}{bz-xy}$.  Is there any other context to the question?  What have you tried?

Comment: Yes I see it. But if We dont know its answer, how to get this ratio? @abiessu

Comment: Assume that you dont know answers, with which calculations you reach these answers. @abiessu

Comment: The initial ratio starts from $\frac {dy}{xy-bz}=\frac {dz}{xz+by}$, and then cross-multiplication/division results in $\frac {dz}{dy}=\frac {xz+by}{xy-bz}$.  Since the numerator and denominator are linear with respect to $y,z$, and the denominator changes negatively in $z$ with respect to the numerator, the integral of the quantity should be negative relative to the original.

Comment: Okay, I understand the first one $c_1$. Thanks a lot. Well, how to get $c_2$. If you Will say it, I am thanksful to you so much. @abiessu

Answer (score 1):

To find $c_2=v(x, y, z)$ you can use the second and third ratios. Namely, multiplying second ratio by $y$ and third ratio by $z$ and addind you get $$\frac{ydy+zdz}{x(y^2+z^2)}$$ and equating this to the first one you have 
$$\frac{dx}{x^2+b^2}=\frac{ydy+zdz}{x(y^2+z^2)}.$$ Now letting $u= y^2+z^2$($\Rightarrow\frac{1}{2}du=ydy+zdz$) leads to a separable ODE:  $$\frac{xdx}{x^2+b^2}=\frac{du}{2u}.$$ Integrating this you find $$\ln (x^2+b^2)=\ln u+\ln c_2$$ or    $c_2(y^2+z^2)=x^2+b^2$.

Comment: I thought the first one was $\frac {dx}{x^2+b^2}$...  And how does your $c_2$ relate to the one given as an answer of $c_2=c_1y+z$?